# Using twitter coordinates in OSGeo library

Tags: python, coordinates, latitude-longitude, osgeo, twitter

I have twitter data with coordinates such as: [-7.2377761, 112.73091137]

I'm working with a python geo library called osgeo. The sample code indicates creating a point like this.

```
point = osgeo.ogr.Geometry(osgeo.ogr.wkbPoint)
point.SetPoint(0, 474595, 4429281)
```

The values above do not look like lat/lon. How do I perform the conversion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing in your Question to suggest that you need to perform a conversion.

Instead, I would try:

```
point = osgeo.ogr.Geometry(osgeo.ogr.wkbPoint)
point.SetPoint(0, 112.73091137, -7.2377761)
```

The original values look like they are from a projected coordinate system whereas you appear to be receiving Twitter data in a geographic coordinate system but both are just numbers.